# crash when back to game scene?

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

when the game scene is done, and i replace to menuScene , everything is ok, but when i replace it back to the gameScene , i allways get the same crash, and just cant figure out what could be the cause to this:

the crash is in the `CCscheduler.m` class in the next method :

```
-(void) update: (ccTime) dt
{
    if( elapsed == - 1)
        elapsed = 0;
    else
        elapsed += dt;
    if( elapsed >= interval ) {
        impMethod(target, selector, elapsed); **//this line gets exc_BAD ! !**
        elapsed = 0;
    }
}
@end
```

any direction? is it memory? or timers? what should i check for ?
thanks.

Comment: Need more information on impMethod. Also this is a very specific question about your code.

Comment: CCScheduler is trying to send a message to a deallocated object. Search for NSZombieEnabled and read this: http://www.learn-cocos2d.com/2011/10/xcode-4-debugging-crashcourse/

Answer (score 0):

Well, it seems to me that you haven't unscheduled all selectors and the function is called on a deallocated object. Try calling [self unscheduleAllSelectors] on your scenes before replacing them.